# Prevent PHP variable from automatically displaying on the page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having a strange occurrence that I haven't seen before. I have created the following variable:

```
$post_type = the_field('select_post_type');
```

so that I can use that variable in other code (using WordPress advanced custom fields). However, at the point where I write that line of code, it actually outputs its value onto the page. The query is working correctly, so it is properly reading the variable otherwise. I haven't seen a variable do this before... any ideas why or how I can fix it?

Here is the full code for context:

```
<?php $post_type = the_field('select_post_type'); 
// the variable is actually outputting onto the page right here

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type, 
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

I've used variables in WordPress queries before and haven't had this happen, so I'm not sure why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_field` automatically echo's use `get_field` instead

Comment: Yep, that was it. I realized it myself a few minutes after I posted. However, then it doesn't work in the query. I tried `'post_type' => echo $post_type,` but that produced an error. So I skipped the variable and wrote `post_type' => the_field('select_post_type')`to get it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Lindsay Why would you want to echo something during array assignment? `'post_type' => $post_type` and `post_type' => get_field('select_post_type')` should work just fine.

Comment: I don't know why `get_field` isn't working in the array assignment, but it isn't pulling in all the posts from that post type. it stops at 10, so it seems to be ignoring my `posts_per_page`. But if I use `the_field` it returns all the posts.

Comment: Nevermind. I found my problem. Yes, get_field works in the query too. Thanks.